# how do I change a dynamically created property from a Event function?

Tags: c#

I have a FlowLayoutPanel being created dynamically with my code, I would like to reposition the panel to the center of my screen on load and resizing like I was able to do with my Label.

problem is since flp isn't in Form2.Designer.cs I get an error when I call it the same way I did with the label.

Error   1   'SCA_Up_Tool.Form2' does not contain a definition for 'flp' and no extension method 'flp' accepting a first argument of type 'SCA_Up_Tool.Form2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(List<IPAddress> addresses)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flp.AutoScroll = true;
        flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        flp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 67);
        flp.AutoSize = false;
        flp.Height = 600;
        flp.Width = 1110;
        flp.WrapContents = false;
    }
}

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - this.label1.Width) / 2;
        this.flp.left = (this.ClientSize.Width - this.flp.width / 2);
    }

    private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - this.label1.Width) / 2;
        this.flp.left = (this.ClientSize.Width - this.flp.width / 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move it to the outer scope. If you need to access a variable outside the method, then it shouldn't be a local variable. Promote the local to instance field.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    public Form2(List<IPAddress> addresses)
    {
        InitializeComponent();    

        flp.AutoScroll = true;
        flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        flp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 67);
        flp.AutoSize = false;
        flp.Height = 600;
        flp.Width = 1110;
        flp.WrapContents = false;
    }
}
```